# Is it possible to not add a new line in a listbox with each input?

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I have a winforms app that takes in user input, and adds it to a list. This list is then displayed in a listbox.

My issue is that I want the listbox to display the individual items once only on one line.
Currently it would look like this:

```
Product    Price    Quantity
Bread      1.20     1
Bread      2.40     2
Bread      3.60     3
Eggs       1.50     1
Eggs       3.00     2
```

I would like it to display:

```
Product    Price    Quantity
Bread      3.60     3
Eggs       3.00     2
```

Is it possible to achieve this?

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lbBasket.DisplayMember = "ProductName";
        try
        {
            string name = textBoxProduct.Text.ToString();
            decimal price = Convert.ToDecimal(textBoxPrice.Text);
            int quantity = Convert.ToInt32(textBoxQuantity.Text);

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBoxQuantity.Text))
            {
                shoppingBasket.AddProduct(name, price);
                lbBasket.Items.Add(textBoxProduct.Text);
                lbPrice.Items.Add(shoppingBasket.BasketTotal);
                lbQuantity.Items.Add(shoppingBasket.NumberOfTotalQuantities);
            }
            else
            {
                shoppingBasket.AddProduct(name, price, quantity);
                lbPrice.Items.Add(shoppingBasket.BasketTotal);
                lbQuantity.Items.Add(shoppingBasket.NumberOfTotalQuantities);

                foreach (OrderItem item in shoppingBasket)
                {
                    if (item.ProductName == name)
                    {
                        lbBasket.Items.Add(item.ProductName);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: show code how you added values to listbox

Comment: Can you not use a dictionary for the items added an keep a running total of the price for each unique item. Then rebind the list each time a new item is added

Comment: @RayB151 - You seem to be using three different list boxes.  So no, I don't think you can achieve what you want that simply.  If you were using a single listbox then yes.  But where you are asking for either the items with the highest value or the highest quantity to be shown (extrapolated from your example), there is no actual link between the two listboxes which show this data.

Comment: Ah, okay. I thought this was easier with three listboxes but I will change to only the one if this would make it possible.

Comment: I'll add a complete solution shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a full example showing you how you could use a single ListBox.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            lbBasket.Items.Add(new Basket("Name 1", (decimal) 1.00, 1));
            lbBasket.Items.Add(new Basket("Name 2", (decimal) 2.00, 2));
        }

        private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var newItem = new Basket(txtName.Text, Convert.ToDecimal(txtPrice.Text), Convert.ToInt32(txtQuantity.Text));

            var existingItem =
                lbBasket.Items.Cast<Basket>()
                    .FirstOrDefault(li => li.Name.Equals(newItem.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
            // There is something there 
            if (existingItem != null)
            {
                // You already have the best one
                if (existingItem.Price > newItem.Price)
                {
                    // Do nothing
                    return;
                }
                // Price is the same
                if (existingItem.Price == newItem.Price)
                {
                    lbBasket.Items.Remove(existingItem);
                    newItem.Quantity += existingItem.Quantity;
                    lbBasket.Items.Add(newItem);
                }
                // Remove the old item and add the new one
                else if (existingItem.Price < newItem.Price)
                {
                    lbBasket.Items.Remove(existingItem);
                    lbBasket.Items.Add(newItem);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                lbBasket.Items.Add(newItem);
            }
        }
    }

    public class Basket
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }

        public Basket(string name, decimal price, int quantity)
        {
            Name = name;
            Price = price;
            Quantity = quantity;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Name + " £" + Price + " " + Quantity;
        }
    }
}
```

When you don't specify a DisplayMember then ToString is called, so I have overridden than in the Basket class to display how you might like it displayed.  Edit it for your own needs, but this has the basic log in that you need and should help you on your way.  If you have any questions feel free to ask... :)

The logic is that if the name already exists then it will check the price, if the price is the same in the new item it will check the quantity, if the quantity is higher it will update.  If the price is higher it will update.  In all other cases, no update will be made.

Comment: This looks like it may work for me. I'll need to tweak some things as I have a separate dll with methods and properties but I think I have the right idea, many thanks!

Comment: No problem.  If you have any more issues just let us know! :)

Comment: That all works fine, except I would like it to update the quantity and price.

At the moment if I specify a quantity of 4, it will set it to 4. (I have an add button on the form). If I press it again, nothing changes, where as I would like it to then read a quantity of 8 (and price corresponding).
Am I able to do that?

Comment: Up vote my comments and I'll accept that as a bribe to do it for you ;)

Comment: Didn't even know that was possible! :P

Comment: This works, however it's adding a single duplicate?
If I add twice, I get two items(if I keep pressing add, It doesn't add any more duplicates). But the quantity is updating correctly thank you!

Comment: It works in my app (if you run my code as is)... Could you try my app and if it fails give me some steps to replicate?

Comment: My bad, I didn't remove the other code from the second `if` statement so it was adding two new items. But now what I'm getting is that if I were to change the price, the quantity resets?

Comment: Resets to what?  Is there some default value?  I believe that I have answered this question properly.  If you want more help, would you mind asking it in another question?  Just be clear about what you want, saying "if the price is higher then I want X to happen" and explaining all of your rules.  Then post back here and I'll take a look at your question and answer it :)  Sorry, but SO frowns upon answering loads of questions in a single post...

Comment: Okay, I shall. And it is resetting to initial value of quantity that I specify. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Just add code similar to follows:

```
foreach(listboxitem itm in lbBasket)
{
  if(itm.toString()!=textBoxProduct.Text)
  {
    lbBasket.Items.Add(textBoxProduct.Text);
  }
}
```

Likewise keep loop for all the 3 listboxes you are having.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with LINQ :

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<ShoppingBasket> bag = new List<ShoppingBasket>();

        bag.Add(new ShoppingBasket("Bread", 1.20M, 1));
        bag.Add(new ShoppingBasket("Bread", 2.40M, 2));
        bag.Add(new ShoppingBasket("Bread", 3.60M, 3));

        bag.Add(new ShoppingBasket("Eggs", 1.50M, 1));
        bag.Add(new ShoppingBasket("Eggs", 3.000M, 2));


        var result = from x in bag
                    group x by x.Product into g
                   select new ShoppingBasket(g.Key, g.Max(x => x.Price),
                   g.Max(x => x.Quantity));
    }
}
public class ShoppingBasket
{
    public string Product { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    public ShoppingBasket(string product, decimal price, int quantity)
    {
        this.Product = product;
        this.Price = price;
        this.Quantity = quantity;
    }
}
```